# Use one query value in another query Neo4j CQL

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to make database of Bookstore where customers can buy books. There is lables Book, BookCategory, Customer, Invoice. I am using relation INVOICEITEM between invoice and books. i added property **netTotal** in invoice to store the sum value of books related in INVOICEITEM with invoice. I tried to get total value of books which is related to invoice.

```
MATCH (n:Invoice {id:'inv001'})-[:INVOICEITEM]->m RETURN SUM(m.price)
```

and i tried to change netTotal propery of invoice by using this command.

```
MATCH (n:Invoice{ id: 'inv001' }) SET n.netTotal = ((n:Invoice {id:'inv001'})-[:INVOICEITEM]-> m RETURN SUM(m.price))
```

but it returns an error. I am new to neo4j and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query to update `netTotal` on the Invoice node should be:

```
MATCH (n:Invoice {id: 'inv001'})-[:INVOICEITEM]->(m:Book) 
WITH n, SUM(m.price) AS netTotal
SET n.netTotal = netTotal
```

Calculate the sum of the `Book` prices using a `WITH` statement to bring that value along to a `SET` statement to update the `netTotal` property on `Invoice` `n`. Note that you also need to specify `n` in the `WITH` statement to bring that bound variable through the query as well. More info on `WITH` statement [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-with.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. very helpful.